# Find last record in nested list using linq

Tags: linq

I have a nested xml something like this.

```
 < H>

   < FP >
       < Name="FP1"/>

       < R >
       < Name = "R1"/> 

            < O>
            < Name="O1"/>
            < /O>
            < O>
                < Name="O2"/>
            < /O>
     < /R>       
     < R>
     < Name = "R2"/>
         < O>
    < Name="O4"/>
          < /O>
     < /R>
< /FP>

< FP>
    < Name="FP2" />

    < R>
          < Name = "R3"/>

          < O>
             < Name="O5"/>
          < /O>
          < O>
             < Name="O6"/>
          < /O>
    < /R>
< /FP>

   < R> 
       < Name="R4"/>
       < O>
    < Name="O7"/>
   < /O>
        < O>
            < Name="O8"/>
        < /O>
     < /R>
 < R>
     < Name="R5"/>
     < O >
          < Name="O9"/>
     < /O>
  < /R>

< /H>
```

I am using deserialization to read this xml.

Here is my deserialization class:

```
[XmlRoot("H")]
public class ReplyH
{
    [XmlElement("FP")]
    public List<ReplyFP> FPs;

    [XmlElement("R")]
    public List<ReplyR> Rs;

}

public class ReplyFP
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name;

    [XmlElement("R")]
    public List<ReplyR> Rs = new List<ReplyR>();
}


public class ReplyR
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name;

    [XmlElement("O")]
    public List<ReplyO> Os = new List<ReplyO>();
}


public class ReplyO
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name;
}
```

I need to iterate over the O tags.

something like foreach(var O in H.FP.R.O) and foreach(var O in H.R.O)

1). I need to find the last `<O>` tag in  which in the above sample is 
< O> < Name = "O9" /> < /O>`.
2). I also need to get the parent`R`Name and`FP`Name if exists for a particular`O`

How can I get this using linq / lambda expression?

Thanks

Comment: Can I see your deserialization code? I'd like to know what form the data takes once it's deserialized.

Answer (score 1):

Here's using Xml.Linq: **Update** See also [competing answer for updated question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13131513/85371)

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System;

public class stuff
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var last = doc.Root
            .XPathSelectElements("//H/FP/R/O | //H/R/O")
            .Last();

        Console.WriteLine(last);
        Console.WriteLine("Parent R has name '{0}'", last.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value);

        var granddad = last.Parent.Parent;
        if (granddad.Name == "FP")
            Console.WriteLine("Parent FP has name '{0}'", granddad.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }

    const string xml = @"<H>
        <FP Name=""FP1"">
            <R Name=""R1""> 
                <O Name=""O1""/>
                <O Name=""O2""/>
            </R>       
            <R Name=""R2"">
                <O Name=""O4""/>
            </R>
        </FP>
        <FP Name=""FP2"">
            <R Name=""R3"">
                <O Name=""O5""/>
                <O Name=""O6""/>
            </R>
        </FP>
    <!--
        <R Name=""R4"">
            <O Name=""O7""/>
            <O Name=""O8""/>
        </R>
        <R Name=""R5"">
            <O Name=""O9""/>
        </R>
    -->
        </H>";
}
```

Outputs

```
<O Name="O6" />
Parent R has name 'R3'
Parent FP has name 'FP2'
```

If you uncomment the last section from the XML:

```xml
<!--
    <R Name=""R4"">
        <O Name=""O7""/>
        <O Name=""O8""/>
    </R>
    <R Name=""R5"">
        <O Name=""O9""/>
    </R>
-->
```

The output becomes:

```
<O Name="O9" />
Parent R has name 'R5'
```

Comment: I updated the question with the class to deserialize. this is just a part of a huge xml and a huge deserialization class. So I cant change now to use linq to xml :( hopefully there is a way out

Comment: @user1186390 I've provided [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13131513/85371) to your updated question.

Comment: Thanks much for the response. As to the linq to object answer you posted above, I do have random order of the < R>< O> and < FP>< R>< O> so the < R>< O>s dont necessarily follow the < FP> tags. So the solution here may not work. For the linq to xml, I am implementing this in Win 8 metro style app and looks like there is no System.xml.xpath. that kills it.

Comment: If the ordering is an issue, change your serialization class, there is **no way** around that.

Comment: @user1186390 Regarding "thanks" - On [SO], if you find an answer helpful, upvote it; if it solved you problem, accept it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

To the updated question, an updated answer using Linq-to-objects.

The code is less elegant then the Linq-to-XML falvour, but it works.

> **Notes**
>
> 1. because FPs and Rs are in different collections at the top level, there is **no way** to know their document ordering as in the source XML. I'm assuming Rs follow FPs inside `ReplyH`, like the code shows (and the sample XML seems to suggest too).
> 2. I've had to  fix the serialization classes to use
>
>    ```
>    [XmlAttribute("Name")] public string Name;
>    ```
>
>    where it (accidentally?) said `XmlElement("Name")` in your question

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReplyH doc;
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
            doc = (ReplyH) new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReplyH)).Deserialize(reader);

        var Rs = doc.FPs
            .SelectMany(fp => fp.Rs.Select(r => new { Parent = fp            , R=r }))
            .Concat    (     doc.Rs.Select(r => new { Parent = (ReplyFP) null, R=r }));

        var Os = Rs.SelectMany(r => r.R.Os.Select(o => new { Parent = r, O=o }));

        var lastO = Os.Last();
        Console.WriteLine(lastO.O.Name);

        if (lastO != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent R has name '{0}'", lastO.Parent.R.Name);

            ReplyFP granddad = lastO.Parent.Parent;
            if (granddad != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Parent FP has name '{0}'", granddad.Name);
        }
    }

    const string xml = @"<H>
        <FP Name=""FP1"">
            <R Name=""R1""> 
                <O Name=""O1""/>
                <O Name=""O2""/>
            </R>       
            <R Name=""R2"">
                <O Name=""O4""/>
            </R>
        </FP>
        <FP Name=""FP2"">
            <R Name=""R3"">
                <O Name=""O5""/>
                <O Name=""O6""/>
            </R>
        </FP>
    <!--
        <R Name=""R4"">
            <O Name=""O7""/>
            <O Name=""O8""/>
        </R>
        <R Name=""R5"">
            <O Name=""O9""/>
        </R>
    -->
        </H>";
}

[XmlRoot("H")] public class ReplyH {
    [XmlElement("FP")] public List<ReplyFP> FPs = new List<ReplyFP>();
    [XmlElement("R")] public List<ReplyR> Rs = new List<ReplyR>();
}

public class ReplyFP {
    [XmlAttribute("Name")] public string Name; 
    [XmlElement("R")] public List<ReplyR> Rs = new List<ReplyR>();
}

public class ReplyR {
    [XmlAttribute("Name")] public string Name; 
    [XmlElement("O")] public List<ReplyO> Os = new List<ReplyO>();
}

public class ReplyO {
    [XmlAttribute("Name")] public string Name;
}
```

Output:

```
O6
Parent R has name 'R3'
Parent FP has name 'FP2'
```

Or after un-commenting the last block of XML:

```
O9
Parent R has name 'R5'
```

Comment: @user1186390 This answers your question fully. If you realize the ordering should be maintained, there is a problem with your XSD/Serialization classes anyway. I think the question as-posed is solved by this answer (clearly demonstrated by the exmple).

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I am going to add a dummy FP if there is non for a R and that way I can still use the solutoin above to get the parent and grand parent.